# Graphviz in cmake project build fails - header not found

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files, graphviz

I want to create an example Cmake project in C++ to see if Graphviz can be used in a big project for documentation purposes.
My project structure is whereas I cloned graphviz from github into the external directory and performed `git submodule update --init --recursive`

```
Project
|external
|   graphviz
|main.cpp
|CMakeLists.txt
```

My Cmake file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
    )

add_subdirectory(external/graphviz)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

I use Windows 10 64bit, CLion and as compiler LLVM Clang and followed the guide http://graphviz.org/doc/winbuild.html, so I added `c:\Projekte\Example\external\graphviz\windows\dependencies\graphviz-build-utilities` to my Path environment variable.
Because CMake failed in the beginning as it could not find Bison and Flex I added to the Cmake options `-DBISON_EXECUTABLE="c:\Projekte\Example\external\graphviz\windows\dependencies\graphviz-build-utilities\winflexbison\win_bison.exe" -DFLEX_EXECUTABLE="c:\Projekte\Example\external\graphviz\windows\dependencies\graphviz-build-utilities\winflexbison\win_flex.exe"`
CMake runs now successfully and I could build the project, but it fails when I try to include the gvc header like this, although it shows no error on the include itself

```
#include "external/graphviz/lib/gvc/gvc.h"
int main() {
   //do stuff
   return 0;
}
```

This is the output

```
====================[ Build | Example | Debug_Clang ]===========================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Projekte\Example\cmake-build-debug_clang --target Example
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\Example.dir\main.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/Example.dir/main.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe  /nologo -TP   -m64 /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd -std:c++17  /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\Example.dir\main.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\Example.dir\ -c -- ..\main.cpp
In file included from ..\main.cpp:4:
../external/graphviz/lib/gvc/gvc.h(14,10): fatal error: 'types.h' file not found
#include "types.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The file not found is located at *external/graphviz/lib/common*

**What I tried**

I assume it is a problem with Cmake, so I tried to change my Cmake file. By removing the `add:subdirectory()` command and replacing it with

1.

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/graphviz)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/graphviz)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${GRAPHVIZ_LIB})
```

2. 

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/graphviz)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cgraph gvc)
```

3. instead of target_include_directories()

```
include_directories(SYSTEM ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/graphviz)
```

4. adding to the Cmake options the library path *-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="c:\Projekte\Example\external\graphviz\lib"*

But I always get the same error. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You can also find help at the Graphviz gitlab site:  https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues

Comment: I already checked everything with header, not found, cmake, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question directly in graphviz support forum and got as answer, that it's a known issue with Cmake and linked me to this thread
https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1477

Tl:dr
Graphviz is currently not buildable as as subdirectory in a Cmake project.